# modeling of ring connection + queues

Tags: queue, omnet++

I have a network of n nodes (switch) where each node can be connected to 4 other nodes with bidirectionel links. How can I model queues between nodes ? should I define module for links because links here are gates. Thanks

I am expecting to have a ring network with four connections for each node, and between each node queues in both directions. I try to see routing and queuelib example but I struggle with this topology. Thanks